# How to put list from a list of list in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering how can I generate a dataframe from my list of list

```
A=[['a','b','c'],['c','d','e'],['f','g','h']]
```

such that I obtain a dataframe with only 1 column and 3 rows containing the differents list `['a','b','c']`,`['c','d','e']` and `['f','g','h']` respectively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```py
In [40]: pd.Series(A, name='col').to_frame()
Out[40]:
         col
0  [a, b, c]
1  [c, d, e]
2  [f, g, h]
```

Comment: thanks, that's what I needed

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by casting `A` as a value within a dict.

```py
>>> A=[['a','b','c'],['c','d','e'],['f','g','h']]
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame({'col':A})
         col
0  [a, b, c]
1  [c, d, e]
2  [f, g, h]
```